# OpenBUGS: Hierarchical Model unable to compile

Tags: model, bayesian, jags, winbugs, openbugs

I've implement a model in OpenBUGs from the following data:

[image]

The data consists of 10 independent studies - 5 trials of 2 different medications (Med = 0 or 1) then a total of infected participants for that trial (infected) - and a Total of participants in the trial.

```
bugsData(list(y = df$Infected, n = 10, J = 5 , t = df$Total, x = df$Med) , file="Bugs_Data.txt")
```

My original model can written as:

```
Y[i]|mu[i],t[i] ~ Bin(mu[i], t[i]), i = 1,.....10
logit(mu[i]) = Beta0 + Beta1*x[i]
```

Which I'm able to implement in OpenBUGS like so:

```
model {
## LIKELIHOOD
  for (i in 1:n) {
    y[i] ~ dbin(mu[i], t[i])
    logit(mu[i]) <- Beta0 + Beta1*(x[i])
  }
  ## NORMAL PRIORS 
  Beta0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
  Beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
}
```

However I then would like to implement a hierarchical model, in which the s(i) denotes the trial from column trial where observation i was taken:

```
Y[i]|mu[i],t[i] ~ Bin(mu[i], t[i]), i = 1,.....10
logit(mu[i]) = Beta0,s(i) + Beta1*x[i]
Beta0,j ~ Normal(mu_bo, sigma2_b0), j = 1,....5
```

I've attempted a model to the best of my ability with no success as of yet.

```
model {
## LIKELIHOOD
  for (j in 1:J) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
      y[i] ~ dbin(mu[i], t[i])
      logit(mu[i]) <- Beta0[j] + Beta1*(x[i])
    Beta0[j] ~ dnorm(mu_b0, tau_b0)
    }
  }
  
  ## PRIORS 
  mu_b0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
  tau_b0 ~ dgamma(0.0001, 0.0001)
  sigma2_b0 <- 1 / tau_b0
  Beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
}
```

The current model isn't able to compile with my data as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a vector of length `n` which indexes what group data point `i` belongs to.

```
model {
## LIKELIHOOD
for (i in 1:n) {
  y[i] ~ dbin(mu[i], t[i])
  logit(mu[i]) <- Beta0[group_vec[i]] + Beta1*(x[i])
}
## PRIORS 
mu_b0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
tau_b0 ~ dgamma(0.0001, 0.0001)
sigma2_b0 <- 1 / tau_b0
Beta1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
for(j in 1:J){
  Beta0[j] ~ dnorm(mu_b0, tau_b0)
}
}
```

`group_vec` is of length `n`, and it takes an integer of which group data point `i` belongs to. So, for example, if we had 21 datapoints and 3 groups.

```
groups <- factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 7))
```

then we could construct `group_vec` as

```
group_vec <- as.numeric(groups)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

This is called nested indexing, and it's a really common way to specify hierarchical models, you just supply it along with your data. In your case, you already have trial as an integer. So you could either make `group_vec` be the trial column in your data, or rename `group_vec` in the model to be `Trial`, whichever you prefer.